# Fazer um laço de repetição após realizar funções

Tags: python, loop

Estou com dificuldade neste código, adaptei em duas funções como orientado pelo prof. mas estou com dificuldade na fase final, que pede: utilize `for` ou `while` por n vezes (n equivalendo à quantidade de produtos informada). Dentro da estrutura de repetição, devo chamar a função “verificar_produto”, permitindo que o usuário consiga cadastrar todos os produtos e verificar se teria ou não limite sobrando para comprá-los.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a estruturar essa fase?

```
def obter_limite (salario, idade, limite):
  print('Irei fazer uma análise de crédito para você, para isso preciso apenas de alguns de seus dados. \n')

  salario = float(input('Qual seu salário? '))
  ano_nascimento = int(input('Qual seu ano de nascimento? \n'))

  import datetime
  agora = datetime.datetime.now()
  idade = agora.year - int(ano_nascimento)
  print('Sua idade é: ', idade)

  limite = float(salario * idade / 1.000) + 100
  print('\nJá analisei seu crédito! Você poderá gastar na loja: R${:.2f}'.format(limite))

  return limite
limite = obter_limite(salario, idade, limite)

def verificar_produto (limite):
  produto = input('Informe o nome do produto que deseja comprar: ')
  preço = float(input('Informe o valor: '))

  porcentagem = preço*100/limite
  if porcentagem <= 60:
    print('\nLiberado')
  elif porcentagem <= 90:
    print('\nLiberado ao parcelar em até 2 vezes')
  elif porcentagem <= 100:
    print('\nLiberado ao parcelar em 3 ou mais vezes')
  else:
    print('\nBloqueado')
    print('Escolha outro produto com valor inferior ao seu limite de crédito')

  desconto = float(7)
  if preço >= 23 and preço <= idade:
    print('Você ganhou um desconto, o valor do produto ficará: R${:.2f}'.format(preço - 7))

  return limite, preço, desconto
limite, preço, desconto = verificar_produto (limite)

#Quantidade #laço repetição de produto soma valores e verificação do limite
n = int(input('\nQuantos produtos deseja cadastrar? '))
for n (verificar_produto)
  while preço <= limite
print(verificar_produto)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para repetir algo `n` vezes, você pode usar um `for` juntamente com [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
for _ in range(n):
    # faz algo
```

`range(n)` gera uma sequência de números de `0` a `n - 1` (o que na prática vai fazer com que o *loop* itere por n vezes).

A variável `_` é uma convenção do Python que indica que não me interessa o valor do número (já que nesse caso não vou usar esse valor, só estou usando o `range` para executar algo várias vezes).

Outro detalhe é que não faz sentido a função `obter_limite` receber como parâmetros a idade, o salário e o limite, já que essas informações serão sobrescritas dentro da função. Além disso, `verificar_produto` está acessando a `idade`, mas esta variável só existe dentro de `obter_limite` e não será possível acessá-la fora desta função.

Enfim, pelo que entendi do funcionamento do programa, ficaria assim:

```
import datetime

def obter_limite():
  print('Irei fazer uma análise de crédito para você, para isso preciso apenas de alguns de seus dados. \n')

  salario = float(input('Qual seu salário? '))
  ano_nascimento = int(input('Qual seu ano de nascimento? \n'))

  agora = datetime.datetime.now()
  idade = agora.year - int(ano_nascimento)
  print('Sua idade é: ', idade)

  limite = float(salario * idade / 1.000) + 100
  print('\nJá analisei seu crédito! Você poderá gastar na loja: R${:.2f}'.format(limite))

  # retorna o limite e a idade, que serão usados depois
  return limite, idade

def verificar_produto(limite, idade):
  produto = input('Informe o nome do produto que deseja comprar: ')
  preço = float(input('Informe o valor: '))

  porcentagem = preço * 100 / limite
  if porcentagem <= 60:
    print('\nLiberado')
  elif porcentagem <= 90:
    print('\nLiberado ao parcelar em até 2 vezes')
  elif porcentagem <= 100:
    print('\nLiberado ao parcelar em 3 ou mais vezes')
  else:
    print('\nBloqueado')
    print('Escolha outro produto com valor inferior ao seu limite de crédito')

  desconto = float(7)
  if preço >= 23 and preço <= idade:
    preço -= 7
    print('Você ganhou um desconto, o valor do produto ficará: R${:.2f}'.format(preço))

  # desconta o preço do limite e retorna o novo limite atualizado
  return limite - preço, preço


limite, idade = obter_limite()

n = int(input('\nQuantos produtos deseja cadastrar? '))
for _ in range(n):
    limite, preço = verificar_produto(limite, idade)
```

Repare que a função `verificar_produto` recebe o limite atual e retorna o novo limite atualizado (já descontado do preço do produto que acabou de ser comprado).

Claro que tem outros detalhes para arrumar (se o produto for bloqueado, não deveria pedir para digitar outro produto ou então encerrar? o cálculo da idade não é preciso, pois só leva em conta o ano, etc), mas aí já fugiria um pouco do escopo da pergunta, que era como fazer o *loop*.

Comment: @LetíciaMaciel Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado  útil.

Comment: Ual! Me ajudou na dúvida sobre a estrutura de repetição e ainda esclareceu sobre o detalhe dos parâmetros. Muito obrigada!